# How to download pdf created by dompdf by WinHttpRequest post request from autohotkey

Tags: php, https, autohotkey, dompdf

Below is my autohotkey code to send WinHttpRequest to php to download pdf file from stream function of PHP created by dompdf.

**AutoHotkey:**

```
whr := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
whr.Open("POST", "https://spm/htmltopdf.php",false)
whr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf")
whr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment")
whr.SetRequestHeader("filename","file.pdf'")
whr.Send("html=" . %html%)
version := whr.ResponseText
FileAppend, %version%, *d:\cc.pdf
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //to get data from firefox addon
require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = $_POST["html"];
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
//$output = $dompdf->output();
//file_put_contents("output/file.pdf", $output);
$dompdf->stream("file.pdf");
?>
```

I could get pdf by direct navigation from browser with **GET** method with 'http' protocol. But for this autohotkey script it does nothing. And it gives an error 'The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect'.

Comment: I can't say about the error on certificate but for downloading pdf in dompdf you can use download() function instead of stream() function..

Comment: I couldn't found an example for download() function. It says `Call to undefined method DOMPDF::download()` when I use that function

Comment: In dompdf\www\functions.inc.php there is no download function. Probably could be my version old?

Comment: dompdf has no `download()` method, it's probably specific to a particular implementation. The certificate error could be because you're connecting via HTTPS to (if your sample code is accurate) a non FQDN. Either try a non-secure connection or connect using the domain that matches the certificate.

Comment: Could be the problem in somewhere either in autohotkey or in my firewall or antivirus. Because as the [autohotkey doc](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/URLDownloadToFile.htm#XHR) I tried to connect the same [Url](https://autohotkey.com/download/1.1/version.txt) and autohotkey returns errorlevel as 1 where I could navigate it in browser

Comment: Are you sure your browser did a GET request? Can you provide a copy of the request your browser does? (You can get it from the browser's dev tools (press F12))

Comment: Are you sure that URL of yours is correct? (https://spm/htmltopdf.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this... I think you are confusing server headers with client headers...

ahk

```
whr := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
whr.Open("POST", "https://spm/htmltopdf.php",false)
whr.SetRequestHeader("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
whr.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
whr.Send("html=" . html)
version := whr.ResponseText
FileAppend, %version%, *d:\cc.pdf
```

php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //to get data from firefox addon
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
header('filename: file.pdf');
require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html = $_POST["html"];
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
//$output = $dompdf->output();
//file_put_contents("output/file.pdf", $output);
$dompdf->stream("file.pdf");
?>
```

or since you said your browser was able to get it via GET and with http, try that:

```
whr := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
whr.Open("GET", "http://spm/htmltopdf.php",false)
whr.SetRequestHeader("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
whr.Send()
version := whr.ResponseText
FileAppend, %version%, *d:\cc.pdf
```

Or go with UrlDownloadToFile in the first place:

```
UrlDownloadToFile, http://spm/htmltopdf.php, file.pdf
```